# Android : cursor is empty even return one value

Tags: android

I want to check the records are available or not in my Sqlite table. I tried but the cursor is always return **1** value even if the SQlite databse table is empty, no any record in table. Why return one? How to solve this issue?

```
dbhelper = new MyDbHelper(this);
SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
String count = "select count(*) from ActivityObjectList";
Cursor mcursor = db.rawQuery(count, null);
mcursor.moveToFirst();
int icount = mcursor.getInt(0);
if(icount>0)
{
    Log.e("Record does not found","");
    //leav

}

else
{
    Log.e("Record is exists !!","");
    //populate table
}
```

Comment: why you using getInt(0), use getCount()

Comment: your table is non empty then, use `sqlite3` tool to verify that

Comment: If i used this line  int icount = mcursor.getInt(); even icount is return 1.

Comment: `sqlite3 /path/to/your/database`

Comment: or use `String count = "select * from ActivityObjectList"; Cursor mcursor = db.rawQuery(count, null);` and dump the cursor using `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(mcursor)`

Comment: It means want to say here i have to change = public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1; (public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;)

Answer (score 0):

Use `mcursor.getCount()` to check number of rows.